# Getting a password from secure text in file to a plain text

Tags: powershell

I have a Script in powershell called SecureText.ps1. what it does is it prompts the user for a password and then converts it into gibberish so the password is secured. 
SecuredText.ps1

```
param([string] $FilePath = (([Environment]::GetFolderPath("myDocuments")+"\SecuredText.txt")))
#SecureText.ps1
#Program the secures text that is only accessable to the user. Defaults to the person "MyDoucments"
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$SecurePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString  | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath
$SecurePassword = $null
```

I then try to convert that into plain text with these commands

```
$Password = Get-Content C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Documents\SecuredText.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
Write-Host $PlainPassword
```

I Expect to get the password back, but I just get back the gibberish. How do I get the password and not the gibberish?

Comment: Create a `[pscredential]` object with the securepassword, then call `.GetNetworkCredential().Password`.  Username doesn't matter

Comment: Note: SecureString can only be decrypted on the same user account AND hardware where it was created.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 tried it that way and still got the jiberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e: Some time has passed since I authored this answer, so some knowledge has been gained

You can utilize the `Export-CliXml` and `Import-CliXml` cmdlets that handle serializing `SecureString` / `Credential` objects for you:

```
# an empty username causes focus to be on the password field
$credential = Get-Credential -Message 'Enter password' -UserName ' '

# encryption using DPAPI
$credential | Export-CliXml -Path $Path

# decryption
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path $Path

# accessing the password
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

---

You're generating and decrypting your passwords incorrectly.

```
## Generation
Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter password' -AsSecureString |
    ConvertFrom-SecureString |
    Out-File -FilePath $Path

## Decryption
(New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList @(
    'user',
    ((Get-Content -Path $Path) | ConvertTo-SecureString)
)).GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: OOPS.. forgot to call get network credential when I tried it. thank you!